# image cropping php

Tags: php, image, crop

I want images at the size of 400 height, 800 width px,

if they're under the given size it'll error it out but if they are above (e.x 1200 width 900 height) I want it to crop the image on the center verticaly and horizontally and upload it with the cropped dimensions

some help would be appreciated, some code to give me the idea

Comment: Googling `php crop image` or `php resize image` here or on Google will give you plenty of ideas and code examples!

Comment: http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-thumbnailimage.php

Answer (score 1):

This articles would help you to get started i think

[PHP: Cropping a Rectangle Image to Square using GD](http://www.bitrepository.com/crop-rectangle-image-to-square.html)

[Resize an Image (on the fly) & Keep its Aspect Ratio using PHP and GD](http://www.bitrepository.com/resize-an-image-keeping-its-aspect-ratio-using-php-and-gd.html)

Comment: I DUNNO REALLY HOW I MARK THIS AS SOLVED BUT I GOT IT WORKING USING WIDEIMAGE, awesome library btw.

Comment: Hi To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. or use this help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work